# Convert 2 character into a string

Tags: c++, string, char

I need to convert two numbers from a 2 dimensional array into characters, and then make those two characters one string. for example if i have [0][0], the first number in the array corresponds to a letter character which should be 'A' in this example and the second number corresponds to a number character which should be '1' in this example. I am doing this with the following code:

```
int i, j;
char c, c2;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
       c = i + 'A';
       c2 = j + '1';
```

This gives me the characters I need but then I need to convert these two characters into one string and I'm not quite sure how to do that. I tried `string s = c + c2` but this gives an error for converting trying to convert an int to string.

Comment: [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct a string with an initializer list:

```cpp
string s = {c, c2};
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make 1 single string of all characters if you one to store separately you can use string array to store them.

```
int i, j;
char c, c2;
string s="";
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      c = i + 'A';
      c2 = j + '1';
       s=s+c;
       s=s+c2;
    }
}
```